# Importing a machine from VMware to xenServer

Tags: virtual-machines, xenserver, vmware-workstation, import, convert

I've exported my VM from VMWare and tried importing it into XenServer (xcp-ng 7.6) XenConvert 2.1.1 but I always get this error:

```
Friday, May 24, 2019 11:15:04
XenConvert 2.1.1.2199 Copyright (c) 2001-2009 Citrix Systems, Inc.
Microsoft Windows 7 (Suite=0x00000100) SP 1
Processor Architecture: x64
Number of processors: 4
OVF to XenServer started at Friday, May 24, 2019 11:15:05
Validating OVF Package...
FWD: Warning:2019.5.24.11.15.5,181: Version not set, applying 1.0.0
FWD: Warning:2019.5.24.11.15.6,69: Validate VHS, Unknown hardware type: vmx-08 failing validation.
FWD: Error:2019.5.24.11.15.6,88: OVF Failed Validation, OVERRIDE return success
OVF Package is valid.
Source is C:\Users\RED\Documents\Virtual Machines\owncloudVMware-disk1.vmdk.
Destination is C:\Users\RED\Documents\Virtual Machines.
VMDK to VHD started at Friday, May 24, 2019 11:15:06
Converting VMDK to VHD...
Dismounting VHD...
Failed to find device for VHD with Id 6221 because of system error:  Element not found. (0x00000490)
Failed to get the system directory.
Windows directory is WINDOWS
Scanning for BOOT volume...
*** Warning! ***
Failed to find the Windows Boot Volume.
VHD C:\Users\RED\Documents\Virtual Machines\owncloudVMware-disk1.vhd was not configured for XenServer.
VM may not boot in XenServer.
Dismounting VHD...
VMDK to VHD stopped at Friday, May 24, 2019 11:34:45
Importing OVF Package...
FWD: Debug:2019.5.24.11.34.47,859: OVF.FindSystemIds completed, 1 found
FWD: Debug:2019.5.24.11.34.48,647: OVF.FindRasdByType completed, 1 found
FWD: Debug:2019.5.24.11.34.48,669: OVF.FindRasdByType completed, 1 found
FWD: Debug:2019.5.24.11.34.49,51: Import.Process: DefineSystem completed (bitnami-owncloud-10.1.1-2-r50-linux-debian-9-x86_64)
FWD: Debug:2019.5.24.11.34.49,376: Import.SetIfDeviceIsBootable: Using HostResource to find Disk
FWD: Warning:2019.5.24.11.34.49,388: Import.FindRasdleName: VHD file exists, replacing VMDK with VHD: owncloudVMware-disk1.vhd
FWD: Debug:2019.5.24.11.34.50,337: Found file owncloudVMware-disk1.vhd using VhdStream
FWD: Debug:2019.5.24.11.34.50,531: Import.UploadRawVDI Enter
FWD: Debug:2019.5.24.11.34.50,541: Import.UpdoadRadVDI SRUUID: 173cb437-4e01-4017-0ab4-4be4b9c8ecc2
FWD: Debug:2019.5.24.11.34.50,549: Import.UpdoadRadVDI Label: bitnami-owncloud-10.1.1-2-r50-linux-debian-9-x86_64
FWD: Debug:2019.5.24.11.34.50,560: Import.UpdoadRadVDI Capacity: 16000221184
FWD: Debug:2019.5.24.11.34.51,334: Import.UploadRawVDI::VDI Created
FWD: Debug:2019.5.24.11.34.51,430: Connect To: 160.226.184.91:80
FWD: Debug:2019.5.24.11.34.51,532: Request: PUT /import_raw_vdi?session_id=OpaqueRef:7227acf1-5a4f-48ef-9823-a3981632eec7&task_id=OpaqueRef:ef3459fe-551e-42c6-bed6-24470e11b6e0&vdi=OpaqueRef:f92c43f1-fa25-4b7b-9717-03f7a41f665a http:/1.0

FWD: Debug:2019.5.24.11.34.51,654: ERROR Returned: 400
FWD: Debug:2019.5.24.11.34.51,669: DoHTTP FAILED
FWD: Debug:2019.5.24.11.34.51,679: Import.UploadRawVDI::http.put complete
FWD: Debug:2019.5.24.11.34.56,687: Import.UploadRawVDI Leave
FWD: Debug:2019.5.24.11.34.56,706: OVF.Import.ImportFile leave
FWD: Debug:2019.5.24.11.34.56,717: Import.AddResourceSettingData, recevied autoevent, continuing
FWD: Debug:2019.5.24.11.34.56,717: Import.ImportFileProc (worker thread) completed
FWD: Debug:2019.5.24.11.34.56,725: Import.AddResourceSettingData VDI= OpaqueRef:f92c43f1-fa25-4b7b-9717-03f7a41f665a
FWD: Debug:2019.5.24.11.34.56,741: Import.VerifyUserDevice, checking device: 99
FWD: Debug:2019.5.24.11.34.56,843: Import.VerifyUserDevice, device: 99 will be used.
FWD: Debug:2019.5.24.11.34.56,848: Import.VerifyUserDevice, checking device: 99
FWD: Debug:2019.5.24.11.34.56,943: Import.VerifyUserDevice, device: 99 will be used.
FWD: Error:2019.5.24.11.34.57,39: VBD Create failed: VDI_READONLY
VDI_READONLY
Failed to import the OVF Package.
OVF to XenServer stopped at Friday, May 24, 2019 11:34:57
```

I followed this link: https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX116603

Answer (score 1):

Note that to do something like that, your XenServer should be configured with a default storage repository (SR). You can do that using the **xe** command.

Another similar issue may be encountered if your Default Storage is full, case in which you need to change it.

If that part is fine and import is still now working, do the following:

- Delete the existing transfer VM template
- Open a command line console to the Master
- CD to location /opt/xensource/packages/files/transfer-vm
- Import the transfer VM using the xe vm-import filename=transfer-vm.xva
- Initiate the import of the OVF file

Comment: Hello, I tried all that you said with no success. when I checked for the default SR there was already one, the system's disk. And it's not full there is plenty of space (about 50% of 1TB). So did the last thing you said, but after deleting the transfer VM when i ran the command `xe vm-import filename=transfer-vm.xva`
the output was just this `bede99de-bb48-1a87-2096-aae548d33225` and in XenCenter it shows a VM that fails to import. then i tried anyway to import my VM and it failed. :(